# How could i format these two dictionaries

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries:

```
sampleOne= {'a':4, 'b':7, 'c':3, 'd':5}
sampleTwo= {'a':6, 'b':3, 'c':7, 'd':2}
```

i have tried using:

```
for key,value in sampleOne:
     print(key,value)
for key,value in samepleTwo:
     print(key,value)
```

But this method is not working, I want the result to look like this:

```
a    4    6
b    7    3
c    3    7
d    5    2
```

However mine is looking like this:

```
a    4
b    7
c    3
d    5
a    6
b    3
c    7
d    2
```

Would appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> sampleOne= {'a':4, 'b':7, 'c':3, 'd':5}
>>> sampleTwo= {'a':6, 'b':3, 'c':7, 'd':2}
>>> for k in sampleOne.viewkeys() | sampleTwo.viewkeys(): # On Py 3 use .keys() instead
        print k, sampleOne.get(k, 0), sampleTwo.get(k, 0)


a 4 6
c 3 7
b 7 3
d 5 2
```

If you need the letters in order change this line:

```
for k in sampleOne.viewkeys() | sampleTwo.viewkeys()
```

to

```
for k in sorted(sampleOne.viewkeys() | sampleTwo.viewkeys())
```

Comment: everything prints off fine, but then i obtain a keyerror 'X'. Do you know what this means? Plus thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2105660 One of your dicts has a key that the other one doesn't, I'll update the code to give it a default value of `0` in that case, you could change the default value if you want

Comment: oh thanks for fast response, but it says 'dict' object has no attribute viewkeys im using sorted(sampleOne.viewkeys())

Comment: @user2105660 oh right on python 3 it should just be `.keys()`

Comment: Yep i accepted the answer, one more quick question though. Now that i used the keys() function, the sort no longer works. Do you know how i could sort it now? Thanks!